# awk code error for removing duplicate records between 2 files

Tags: awk

I found this bit of awk code that compares the first column of two files and then deletes the duplicate records of the second file.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

When I run the code, I get an error that says: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

I am very new to awk coding, so I am not too sure what is causing the error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS is this? What version of awk?

Comment: windows 7 pro,  gawk version 3.1.6 (looks like the release date was back in 2008).

Comment: It's not an awk issue. What environment are running this script under `cygwin`, `cmd`, `powershell`... and which shell are you using?

Comment: If this is `cmd.exe` try double quotes around the command script. I don't think `cmd.exe` likes single quotes. Or better, try something saner than `cmd.exe` to run things.

Comment: cmd and windows powershell 2.0

Comment: SUCCESS!  that did it!  Thank You!  I somehow need to give you some rep!

Comment: Usual advice - don't run command-line awk scripts in Windows as the Windows quoting rules make it very complicated and difficult to get right. Install and use cygwin instead and if that's not possible for some reason then put your awk script in a file and execute it using `awk -f scriptfile inputfile`.